# Sqlite queries inside the constructor are executing twice?

Tags: sqlite, angular2-nativescript

I need to create multiple tables in local DB using the Nativescript-Sqlite plugin. When I tried, the queries written inside the constructor is executing twice. I found that by given alert for each table creation code.
How should I rectify this?

```js
constructor(private page: Page, private userService: UserService) {
    this.user = new User();

   (new Sqlite("my.db")).then(db => {
         database = db;
          db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT)").then(id => {
                  alert("table1 insertd");              }, error => {
                console.log("CREATE TABLES ERROR", error);
            });

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people2 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT)").then(id => {
                    alert("table2 insertd");        }, error => {
                console.log("CREATE TABLE ERROR", error);
            });


        }, error => {
            console.log("OPEN DB ERROR", error);
        });}
```

My development environment- 
Nativescript with angular2
IDE - Visual Studio Code

-Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could be injecting this component in multiple place -- perhaps early in your app's lifecycle (app.module.ts perhaps?). I would first check to see if the **constructor** is being called twice. If it is, you're component is being instantiated twice.